# My Buildpath seems correctly, but i'm having a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, selenium

i'm trying to use Selenium for web automation, but i'm having NoClassDefFoundError.

I have the selenium-java-2.52.jar  on my Referenced libraries and my code cant run.

Here's a sample of my code:

`import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Tipo_helo_World {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("Interfile");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='PesquisaGoogle']")).click();
    }

}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **selenium-java-2.52.jar** and **all JAR files in folder libs** to your references library.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Have a look at my workplace folders, they already have the selenium-java library.
[Link to Eclipse image](http://imgur.com/XZnGDdN)
[Link to Workplace image](http://imgur.com/9dKNZ4e)
[Link to Libs image](http://imgur.com/5h915oK)

Answer (score 0):

This is where a dependency manager (like Maven) can help you, versus manual copying of libs:

`FirefoxDriver` is contained within the `selenium-firefox-driver-<version>.jar`, which ordinarily would be included as a dependency of the aforementioned `selenium-java-<version>.jar`

At the very least, the Firefox driver JAR will in turn need `selenium-remote-driver-<version>.jar`, then `selenium-api-<version>.jar`, and perhaps also `selenium-support-<version>.jar`

Comment: i downloaded the selenium server.jar and the command to open the browser worked, but the findelement don't... any advices?